# meter un array en una sola fila de mysql y despues poder sacarla de la base de datos y manejarla con un for each para mostrarla

Tags: php, mysql, array, pdo, insert

hola muy buenas my pregunta es la siguiente tengo un array que recogo de un formulario de html que es el siguiente

```
<div class=\"col-md-6\"><label> producto quimico$i: </label><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"productoquimico[]\" id=\"productoquimico$i\" value=\"\" placeholder=\"escribe el quimico\" maxlength=\"30\" autocomplete=\"off\" /> </div>
```

[image: campo donde quiero guardarlo]

donde productoquimico[] es el array que estoy recogiendo mediante php el cual quisiera insertar en un campo de una base de datos y despues recuperarlo para poder mostrarlo utilizando PDO para gestionar la consulta y despues hacer un for each para porder mostrarlo en otra pagina con una funcion les agradeceria mucho su ayuda muchas gracias de ante mano

al final hice lo siguiente

```
try{
        $db = getDB();

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT qumicos_formula, porcentajes_formula,url_videos_formula FROM formulas WHERE `titulo_formulas`='estrellas rojas de clorato'");
        $stmt->execute();
        // para sacar el objeto que vamos a referenciar abajo
        $data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);// para sacar el objeto que vamos a referenciar abajo
        $count=$stmt->rowCount();// cuenta las filas y las mete en un array
        $db = null;
        $array_quimicos = json_decode($data->qumicos_formula,TRUE); 
        $array_porcentajes = json_decode($data->porcentajes_formula,TRUE);
        $array_url_videos = json_decode($data->url_videos_formula,TRUE);
        foreach ($array_quimicos as $value ) {
            echo $value."<br>";

        }
        foreach ($array_porcentajes as $value) {
            echo $value."<br>";
        }
        foreach ($array_url_videos as $value) {
            echo $value;
        }


}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es almacenar este array como JSON. Primero, en MySQL definir tu campo como TEXT (en caso de que tu array sea muy grande) para almacenar la data. Luego en tu php realiza un json_encode a tu array y lo almacenas.

```
$data = [
    "item1" => "data 1",
    "item2" => "data 2",
    "item3" => "data 3",
];

$json_data = json_encode($data);
```

Luego almacenas $json_data en tu base de datos. Ahora, para recuperar la data como array, realizas a inversa, o sea un json_decode

```
// Query MySQL
$array_data = json_decode($db->row, true);
```

Comment: vale mi pregunta ahora es como guardo ese array que me vienes de html tendria que recorrerlo  es ahi donde me hago un lio al pasar el array que me llega del html5 a json   $data = [
    "item1" => "data 1",
    "item2" => "data 2",
    "item3" => "data 3",
];

Comment: se que se me guarda como array no asociativo y quiero saber como manipularlo ya que cuando lo extraigo de mysql me dice que no puede decodificarlo ni sacarlo de un objeto

Comment: yo los estoy guardando como los tengo en la base de datos que uestro arriba y no se como llegar al paso de json dcode si se me puediera dar un ejemplo con pdo